# How to find html nodes via javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am not an html or javaScript programmer, and as such, I have a question in regards to finding html nodes via javaScript?

I am currently deciding on whether to use class attributes or data attributes for each html node and am not sure if there is a standard practice on how to find html nodes via javaScript?

Here is the situation:

I have x amount of html nodes that need to be found via javaScript. These html nodes are sometimes found by more than one javaScript function, and need to be identified with different attributes for this purpose. So, I am saying that one html node needs to have more than one attribute in some situations, and the same attribute (or equivalent) needs to be used across multiple html nodes in some situations.

Because of the above, I am thinking that using class attributes is correct.

Here is an example:

Html node 1:

```
<div class="attribute-1 attribute-2"></div>
```

Html node 2:

```
<div class="attribute-2"></div>
```

JavaScript function 1:

Needs to get all html nodes with the attribute:

```
attribute-1
```

JavaScript function 2:

Needs to get all html nodes with the attribute:

```
attribute-2
```

I have found this resource that states that this should not be done: http://roytomeij.com/blog/2012/dont-use-class-names-to-find-HTML-elements-with-JS.html

I have also found the following information:

There are 5 main ways of querying DOM:

1. getElementById
2. getElementsByTagName
3. getElementsByName
4. getElementsByClassName (except IE<9)
5. querySelector (except IE<8 and IE8 in compat mode)

So basically, I am asking, how should html nodes be found using javaScript, where I am decorating the html nodes myself? Should I use classes, data attributes or something else?

Comment: If Javascript provides you with 5 different ways of querying nodes, then why are you confused. Use the one which suits your use-case the best. Rest is all opinions.

Comment: Every function has its own purpose and should be used accordingly. For eg: I have a `<div id="blog" class="tile"></div>`. For this if I used *getElementsByClassName* then I might get more than one divs and will have to filter it. similarly if I want all divs with class who have *tile* class, use getElementsByClassName instead of searching them individually.

Answer (score 0):

It strongly depends on the structure of your HTML page and on which is your objective.

For instance, the element:

```
<tag id="myId" class="myClass"/>
```

can be retrieved by either of the following ways:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myId"); // 1 element
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass"); // 1+ elements
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("tag"); // 1+ elements
```

Notice that:

- the `id` property guarantees that, if the HTML page is designed properly, there should be just an element with the specified id in the page, so by using `getElementById()` you will retrieve a single element from the DOM
- `getElementsByClassName()`, `getElementsByTagName()` and `getElementsByName()` retrieve elements based on their class, their tag and their name. Since these are not unique (i.e., there could me more than one element reporting the same class, tag or name), you will retrieve a list of elements, which you have to properly traverse to find the element you are looking for

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to use jQuery for your purposes.

get element by id:

```
$('#element_id'):
```

get elements for a given class:

```
$('.element_class')
```

full docs here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I believe `jQuery` is not tagged in, in question.

Comment: The question asks solution for JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: He said he's not an HTML/JS developer, maybe he just never heard of jQuery.

Comment: If he doesn't know jQuery, by all means leave him in peace.

Comment: What's wrong with suggesting someone a tool that helps solving the problem? He never said "I require pure JS".